# Local late initialization in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I late-initialize a variable in a funtion, since `lateinit` is not allowed for local variables? Otherwise, what is the good pattern for this case:

```
private fun displaySelectedScreen(itemID: Int) {
    //creating fragment object
    val fragment: Fragment
    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    when (itemID) {
        R.id.nav_schedule -> fragment = ScheduleFragment()
        R.id.nav_coursework -> fragment = CourseworkFragment()
        R.id.nav_settings -> {
            val i = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
    //replacing the fragment, if not Settings Activity
    if (itemID != R.id.nav_settings) {
        val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)// Error: Variable 'fragment' must be initialized
        ft.commit()
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`when` is an expression, so

```
val fragment: Fragment = when (itemID) {
    R.id.nav_schedule -> ScheduleFragment()
    R.id.nav_coursework -> CourseworkFragment()
    ...
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

will work for this use case.

There is no `lateinit` equivalent for local variables. Other language constructs like `try` or `if` are expressions as well, so this is never needed.

---

**Update 2017-11-19**

Kotlin 1.2 supports `lateinit` for local variables, so

```
lateinit val fragment: Fragment
```

works starting with Kotlin 1.2.

Comment: Almost perfect. But now I have a problem with the 3rd case, scince I'm not assigning anything, it says 'Type mismatch. Required: Fragment, Found: Unit"

Comment: Then you have to make the variable nullable like this: `val fragment: Fragment? = ...` and end the 3rd block with the line `null`.

Comment: Well, null types are exactly what I was trying to avoid. Thanks anyway.